# Validation of each field in JSON response using karate API

Tags: validation, response, karate

I want to validate particular fields in the response whether it is integer or float(ex: fullbathrooms field). I tried below code but getting match failed error. Could you please help here ?.....Thanks

```
Given path '/property-client'
And request {"address": <address>,"city": <city>,"state": <state>,"zipCode": <zipCode>}
When method post
Then status 200
And print response

And match response == {fullbathrooms:'#number'}
```

Examples:
|read('testFile1.csv')|

Error : match failed: EQUALS

Actual response:

{
"success": true,
"message": {
"version": "1.0",
"response": {
"id": "94568859",
"type": "express",
"responseheader": null,
"reportdata": {
"property": {
"source": null,
"type": null,
"dom": null,
"propertytype": "Single Family Residence",
"standardtype": null,
"address": {
"documentid": null,
"number": "150",
"directional": null,
"street": "BRIDGE",
"suffix": "RD",
"postdirectional": null,
"unit": "",
"city": "HILLSBOROUGH",
"state": "CA",
"zip": "94010",
"zipplus4": "6908",
"fulladdress": "150 BRIDGE RD, HILLSBOROUGH, CA 94010"
},
"info": {
"type": null,
"fips": "6081",
"county": "San Mateo",
"bedrooms": "5",
"bathrooms": "6.50",
"fullbathrooms": "6.50",
"totalrooms": "0",
"livingarea": "7750",
"totallivingarea": "7750",
"landarea": "41382",
"landareatype": null,
"pool": "true",
"landvalue": "6904800",
"improvementvalue": "3284414",
"assessedvalue": "10189214",
"assessedyear": "2021",
"taxvalue": "11746898",
"taxyear": "2021",
"deliquentyear": null,
"yearbuilt": "2011",
"propertytax": null,
"approxage": "11",
"parcelnumber": "032-400-110",
"titlecompany": null,
"geocode": {
"latitude": "37.563272",
"longitude": "-122.334442",
"geoqualitycode": ""
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Please take some time to read the documentation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-contains

I'm not going to refer to your response dump (which by the way is not valid JSON), but give you a simple example. Please pay attention to the structure of your JSON. And note that the `6.50` is a string not a number in your response.

```
* def response = { "foo": { "bar": { "fullbathrooms": "6.50" } } }
* match response.foo.bar == { fullbathrooms: '#string' }
```

If you want to validate numbers within strings, please refer other answers, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+number+regex